# Integral of Partial Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve the following PDE and find G=G(x,y):
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=0
$$

The function F=F(x,y) is known. I rewrote this equation as:
$$
G(x,y)= -\int{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}dy + c(x).
$$
The first part of the right handside is calculated easily. How should I go about finding the $c(x)$ term?

Comment: You can't find it unless you have some associated data for $G$, such as the explicit form for $G(x,0)$.

Comment: Since no boundary condition is specified in the question, the PDE has an infinity of solutions. This infinity of solution is provided by the arbitrary function $c(x)$. Thus it is absurd to try to find a particular function $c(x)$ until some boundary condition be specified in the wording of the question.